# Vuejs Cannot read properties of undefined? But properties are defined

Tags: javascript, json, api, vue.js

So i have been working on a project of mine and ive come along something really strange which i cant seem to solve.

the issue:
The code beneath with the v-for loop works IF i dont reload the website and just do ctrl + S to save the file (hotloading).

How ever if i do save and reload the page the following error appears: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'edges'). I would like to get the values stored in every node.
How is this possible the value is there. Is there anyway to solve this?

How is it possible that in a hot update/load it works and in a normal reload it doesnt?

Could this be because the API gets requested after VueJs searches for the property?
If anyone knows a solution to this please let me know. All the help is greatly appreciated.

**my data:**

```
{"data":
  {"customers":
    {"edges":[
      {"node": 
        {"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Customer\/543xxxx429","email":"xxxxxx@me.com",
         "phone":null}},
      {"node": 
        {"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Customer\/5653xxxx37","email":"xxxxxxx@live.nl",
         "phone":null}}
      {"node": 
        {"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Customer\/57xxxxx8117",
      "email":"xxxxxxxx@outlook.com",
        "phone":null}}
```

**My code:**

```
                <tr v-for="customer in customers.customers.edges" :key="customer">
                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                    {{ customer.node.id }}
                  </td>
                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                    <!-- {{ test }} -->
                  </td>
                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                    {{ customer.node.email }}
                  </td>
                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                    {{  customer.node.phone }}
                  </td>
                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                    <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
<script setup>
import PageComponent from "/src/components/PageComponent.vue";
import store from "../../store";
import { computed} from "vue";
store.dispatch('getCustomers');

const customers = computed(() => store.state.customers.data);
console.log(customers);

//const customers = computed(() => store.state.customers.data);
</script>
```

**console.log(customers)**
[image: Result console.log(customers)]

**My network tab from chrome:**
[image: Network Tab]

Comment: from your console.log, it looks like there are 2 data nodes still under the customers object. Try fiddling around it.

console.log(customers.data.data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page, `store.state.customers.data` is not yet populated, so the computed value of `customers` is the initial state (probably an empty object), and `customers.customers` would be `undefined`, leading to the error you observed.

One solution is to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when referencing `edges` from `customers.customers` in the `v-for`:

```html
                                         
<tr v-for="customer in customers.customers?.edges">
```

Another solution is to conditionally render the row when `customer.customer.edges` exists:

```html
                                                   
<tr v-for="customer in customers.customers.edges" v-if="customer.customers?.edges">
```

Note: Only Vue 3 supports optional chaining in the template. In Vue 2, you can replace it with an additional truthy check, as seen in this equivalent markup to the above:

```html
<tr v-for="customer in customers.customers.edges" v-if="customers.customers">
```

```html
<tr v-for="customer in customers.customers.edges" v-if="customers.customers && customers.customers.edges">
```